# Dismissing a UIAlertView on any touch

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel, uialertview, touchesbegan

I am trying to use a UIAlertView essentially as a label (no title or buttons, just display text) for aesthetic purposes.  I want to be able to continue to use everything else in the app (touch other buttons, etc.) while the alert view is being shown.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to invoke touchesBegan or a selector using a UITapGestureRecognizer while the alert view is shown.  These both work when the alert view is not shown, but it seems like the alert view disables detection of any touches (other than touching its own buttons if it had them).

Does anyone know a way I could work around this?  Even if I was to create a UILabel and set its background to the alert view image that would work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The alert view puts a new window on top of the entire screen which intercepts touches. It's expressly designed to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to abuse alerts in this manner anyway? It's generally a bad idea to take existing UI and use them in non-standard ways, as well as a possible reason to get rejected.

Your best bet is to just draw the "alert view" yourself, either in code or as a pre-baked image. Unfortunately this means you cannot leverage the built-in code that draws UIAlertView, but it's probably best that you don't try to appear identical to a UIAlertView anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there a way I can access the alert view graphics programmatically?

Comment: Ended up using this alert view image as a stretchable image.  I used it in a UIImageView below a label and it worked out great.  Link:  http://lh3.ggpht.com/_QLwms0mVa4w/S_FsvBgNLtI/AAAAAAAAAqA/ooFM3RIK7Ho/alert_background.png?imgmax=800

Comment: Hi Steve. If you're satisfied with this answer, I would appreciate it if you could choose this as the correct answer to your question.